# Python mocking: how do I change behavior based on input values?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, inversion-of-control

I have a class that I am trying to cover with tests in python.

I have a dependency that's being injected into the class.

```
class UnderTest:
    def __init__(self, dependency):
        self.dependency = dependency
```

I don't really care about the internals of the dependency here, and want to mock it.

So I instantiate the class in my tests, injecting the dependency:

```
dependency = MagicMock()
dependency.some_func = MagicMock(return_value='blue')
under_test = UnderTest(dependency)
```

Later when I want to test the class `UnderTest`, I want the dependency to return a different value based on what parameters were passed to it. So in the code under test, I might have something like

```
value = dependency.some_func('a')
```

but I also want the dependency to return something else when called with a different value.

```
value = dependency.some_func('b')
```

Ideally (and I have seen this in other frameworks), I would be able to configure the mock to return different values, for example (how I would like it to work)

```
dependency.some_func = MagicMock([
    {'called_with': 'a', 'return_value': 'blue'}, 
    {'called_with': 'b', 'return_value': 'green'}
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) attribute to set a callable that returns different values according to its arguments.

```
results = {'a': 'blue', 'b': 'green'}
dependency.some_func = MagicMock(side_effect=lambda arg: results.get(arg, DEFAULT))
```

(The [`DEFAULT` singleton](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.DEFAULT) is used to signal that the normal mock return value is used for arguments not in the dict.)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much